# Jquery and jQuery-Validation-Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery-Validation-Engine found at [GitHub](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and it is working good, but I can't manage one thing ,after form is submitted to create action. Code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#contact-form").validationEngine({
ajaxFormValidation: true,
             onSuccess: function(){
                 alert(1);
             }
            });
        });
```

This is working(data is written into db) but there is no alert. I also tried with onAjaxFormComplete but again nothing. Does someone have experience with this plugin?

Comment: After inserting the data, returns some value from the server?

Comment: Please be careful when tagging.  [tag:jquery-validate] is a totally different plugin.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#contact-form").validationEngine('attach', {
                ajaxFormValidation: true,
                onAjaxFormComplete: function(form, status){
                    alert("The form status is: " +status);
                }  
            });
        });
```

Also remember than on the SUBMIT page(where you send it to the database), you need to gerenate a repsonse back -if the form was submitted or not (true/false).

See:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/phpajax/ajaxValidateSubmit.php