# How to Implement onSuccess() using Jquery Validation Engine?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I am using Jquery Validation Engine http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/ and I just want to reveal a hidden loading gif **once the form has been found to be valid**.

ie

- user submits form
- if form is valid:
  $('#lulus-loading-div').show();

I have tried this, but no luck there:

- [Jquery and jQuery-Validation-Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7428229/1177832)

I seem to be having no luck implementing the onSuccess() callback function.

I don't doubt that it works swimmingly, I am unfortunately ignorant of the correct syntax, and have had no luck with docs : /

At the moment I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#model-form").validationEngine({

           onSuccess: function(){
              $('#lulus-loading-div').show();
           });
        });

 });
```

This calls onSuccess() the first time a single field validates, then if you try to submit form incomplete, it submits without flagging errors.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

if you need any more details please let me know.

Comment: What does your class attribute look like for your <input> tag?  Does it look like <input class="validate[required]">?

Comment: You may want to move away from implementing placeholder text with javascript, and just use the HTML5 'placeholder' attribute on input fields.  You can edit your question to improve readability.  Don't place too much code in the comments.  Please update your questions with better formatted text.  Thanks.

Comment: Different class depending on input. Email:  `class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input"` Text uses checkRequired(): `class="validate[required,funcCall[checkRequired]] text-input"` and file uses similar class to the one you mentioned: `class="validate[required,funcCall[checkRequired]] text-input"`. I am using js for placeholder as it suits for backwards compatibility in this situation, although I think that may be a little off the subject. form can be found here: http://www.lulusmodels.com.au/model-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation Engine does not have anything (working) to accomplish such task.

Assuming that your form uses page reload - but should work with ajax based no-reload submissions as well.

At one time I needed something like it and I wrote a quick'n'dirty hack, which does just that.

I use version 2.5.2

Find this code (around line 240-250)

```
form.trigger("jqv.form.result", [errorFound]);
```

Right before it add this code:

```
if (options.jpAfterSuccessValidation && !errorFound) {
    options.jpAfterSuccessValidation();
}
```

On the very bottom, in default, append to (add after) "fadeDuration"

```
fadeDuration: 0.3,
jpAfterSuccessValidation: false //launches callback, if all fields validate
```

and use it like this:

```
jQuery("#model-form").validationEngine({
    jpAfterSuccessValidation: function(){
    $('#lulus-loading-div').show(); //this will pull-up your info dialog
    }
});
```

Your "lulus-loading-div" will stay visible until page holding form reloads (and form gets submited).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jeffz. Although when I implemented your supplied code, it didn't work (version 2.5.3) - **but** it lead me to my own quick 'n' dirty, just added:      if (!errorFound) {
    $('#lulus-loading-div').show();
   } to the position you suggested to add your code (just before form.trigger line).

Answer (score 1):

The onSuccess bugs are also reported on their Git. Following is a work around snnipet taken from https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/554
:

```
$("#my_form").validationEngine('attach', { 
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){ // when validate is on and the form scan is completed
        if (status == true) { // equiv to success everythings is OK
            // we disable the default from action to make our own action like alert or other function
            form.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // your function or your action

            alert("Successful! Now submitting");
            return true;
        } else {
            // we disable the default from action to make our own action like alert or other function
            form.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // your function or your action

            alert("Errors! Stopping Here");
        }
    },
    promptPosition : "topLeft", 
    scroll: false
});
```

Hope, it helps someone!!!

Answer (score 0):

The "quick 'n'clean solution is to do like this :

```
$("#new_user").validationEngine("attach", {
  promptPosition: "topLeft",
  onFieldSuccess: function() {
    alert("rakoto");
  }
});
```

hope helps. ;)